# How to create BOPF Change Documents?

Tags: abap, cds

I have created a custom Business Object using Transaction BOBX. I would like to implement Change documents for this BO to keep record of all the transactional data changes made to this BO. These Change Documents should contain all the relevant information like the changed object dataset, old & new values, date & time of change along with the person name who has made the changes.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in order to learn how you could get help here.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna use SAP Change Documents, SAP provides a reusable BO /BOFU/CHANGE_DOCUMENT which allows to implement to recored all changes of your BOs. On Business Suite systems the BO is part of the Business Suite Foundation Layer, on S/4 systems it is part of the S/4 Foundation layer. For more details regarding how you can integrate it please check the official help ([Using the Change Document Adaptor](https://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_06/helpdata/en/d9/1c6acb7c524a4999bfa73275c484f5/frameset.htm)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have added sub node /BOFU/CHANGE_DOCUMENT in my custom BO root node and did the necessary configurations mentioned in the link. Now the entries are getting updated in CDPOS and CDHDR.
I want to reuse the change history UI for custom BO. I am new to FPM. I have created FPM OVP application and trying to reuse Webdynpro component /BOFU/CHANGE_DOC_TAB. Could you please give me the detailed steps to use it in my application?